# How to clear Ultragrid cell of System.DateTime DataType

Tags: c#, .net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I am using Ultragrid in c# .net windows application,

I used a column of datatype `System.DateTime`., On page loading it is showing empty (like `'--/--/--'`),

aftrer some validations i want to make that column empty

when am trying to make that column empty, it is taking current date as default or `'01/01/0001'`.

i made defaultvalue to null.

How to make empty that column means it should show like `'--/--/--'`

Comment: you mean '--/--/--' when you have no data bound to it, coz since you say `DateTime` it will move to `DateTime.MinValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably an issue with your `DataSource`, not the grid.

The `DateTime` data type in DotNet is a struct, so it can't be null. If you use a `DataSet`/`DataTable` or `UltraDataSource` as the data source for your grid, then these objects store everything as an object so that they can handle null or `DBNull`. My guess is that you are probably binding the grid to a list of your own custom classes and the DataType of the field is `DateTime` and cannot accept nulls.

If you are using `CLR2`, maybe you can use a `nullable` `DateTime`, instead. You might have to set the `Nullable` property on the column to Nothing, though, since even a `nullable` type can't handle `DBNull`.